# keras-bert load_trained_model_from_checkpoint error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I had a code for loading a BERT model that executed very well, but now it raises me an error

here is the code

model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(
config_path,
checkpoint_path,
trainable=True,
seq_len=SEQ_LEN,
output_layer_num=4
)

now the error it raises is:

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'

The environment settings are as follows:

keras-bert=0.85.0

keras=2.4.3

tensorflow=1.15.2

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your environment settings, when installing packages, try installing them without specifying the specific versions:

```
pip install -q keras-bert
pip install keras
```

**AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'** basically occurs when you mixup `keras` and `tensorflow.keras` as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392672/4401019) explains.

See if that resolves your issue. Also, if you have the following in your code:

```
import keras
from keras import backend as K
```

Try changing them to:

```
from tensorflow.python import keras
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
```

I hope that resolves your issue.

You can check [this article](https://pysnacks.com/bert-text-classification-with-fine-tuning/) for reference.

Comment: Hi and many thanks for ur help. It works now. Thanks again!