# keras-bert load_trained_model_from_checkpoint. 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'

Tags: tensorflow, keras, bert-language-model

I am using Keras==2.2.4, keras-bert==0.85.0, tensorflow-gpu==1.15.0

My code is

```
from keras_bert import load_trained_model_from_checkpoint
model_path = '../wide_deep_nlu/mt_bert_12layer_pretrain/'
paths = get_checkpoint_paths(model_path)
bert_model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(paths.config,paths.checkpoint,seq_len=None)
```

I got error:

```
----> 4 bert_model = load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(paths.config,paths.checkpoint,seq_len=None)
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'
```

Plz help

Comment: Take a look at this solution . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70966772/keras-bert-load-trained-model-from-checkpoint-error

Comment: This solution does not work for me.

Comment: @Felix As the error states, the tuple object does not have layer attribute.
You must add output_layer_num in this line `bert_model=load_trained_model_from_checkpoint(paths.config,paths.checkpoint,output_layer_num,seq_len=None)`. Please go through [this](https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-bert/blob/2d3590dac33b4f097aefbff3d42b630626fd157d/keras_bert/loader.py#L145)  for more details. Let us know if the issue still persists. Thanks!